# Setting paragraph indention

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

How can I set include an indent for each new paragraph? I tried multiple things but I can't seem to fix it. This is my current main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%\title{Nudging People Into Paying Carbon Offsets - The Effect of the Decoy Effect in Flight Booking Processes}
%\shorttitle{Nudging People Into Paying Carbon Offsets}
%\author{\textbf{Student} \\ Nino Oostrom \\ 375181no \\ Rotterdam School of Management \\ Erasmus University \\ Burgemeester Oudlaan 50 \\ 3062 PA Rotterdam}
%\affiliation{\textbf{Coach} \\ Markus Weinmann \\
%\textbf{Co-Reader} \\ Name of Co-Reader}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % numbered headlines

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\input{titlepage}

\input{Texts/00_abstract}

\clearpage

\tableofcontents % create table of contents

%\justify

% Assemble thesis parts
\clearpage

\input{Texts/01_intro} % Introduction
\input{Texts/02_related_work} % Related Work
\input{Texts/03_theory} % Theory & Hypotheses
\input{Texts/04_method} % Method
\input{Texts/05_results} % Results
\input{Texts/06_discussion} % Discussion
\input{Texts/07_conclusion} % Conclusion
\bibliography{bibliography}
\input{Texts/08_appendices}

\end{document}

%
% Please see the package documentation for more information
% on the APA6 document class:
%
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa6
%
```

Comment: The `apa6` class has been superseded by `apa7`. For both classes, the `man` option is for submissions to an APA journal. They want it to be like that, so there's no benefit in changing the layout: you rather risk rejection for the manuscript not being compliant with the specifications. If you're not submitting to the APA, there's no reason for using the class.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide an example that showed the issue, but this is a feature of the `man` option:

with man:

[image]

after removing `man,` from the first line

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%\title{Nudging People Into Paying Carbon Offsets - The Effect of the Decoy Effect in Flight Booking Processes}
%\shorttitle{Nudging People Into Paying Carbon Offsets}
%\author{\textbf{Student} \\ Nino Oostrom \\ 375181no \\ Rotterdam School of Management \\ Erasmus University \\ Burgemeester Oudlaan 50 \\ 3062 PA Rotterdam}
%\affiliation{\textbf{Coach} \\ Markus Weinmann \\
%\textbf{Co-Reader} \\ Name of Co-Reader}

\title{aaa}
\shorttitle{bbb}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % numbered headlines

\begin{document}


aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa 
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa 
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa 
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa 

bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb 
bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb 
bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb 

\end{document}
```